# What's with the recent slew of web questions on SU?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I know they come in now and then, but they were definitely getting closed for a while there. But in the last few days I have seen several "web" questions that didn't get closed. What's going on? Fluke or policy change again?

**Edit**: Examples:

- [Freely available famous quotes database](https://superuser.com/questions/135269/freely-available-famous-quotes-database-closed)

That's all I can find really easily, and it did get closed just now, but I know I've seen a few web questions recently that I was surprised were not closed.

<sub>Personally I'd like to see a StackExchange 2.0 community spring up for these sorts of questions.</sub>

Comment: It's Web 3.0 maaan!

Comment: @Nathaniel Could you provide some examples, please?

Comment: @Jonathan 1 added. Sorry, couldn't find more very easily.

Comment: I noticed that the Community user did prod a couple recently so I voted to close & hoped that others spotted them too.

Comment: If I spot one on the front page, it's dead!

Answer (score 2):

People with moderating powers are not all the time on the site, so there are some questions which are going through.

Don't hesitate to flag for moderator's attention if you see a question which is off-topic, but can't vote to close yet.

Comment: I'm on the site a lot, just not always looking for questions to close ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This correlates with [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48013/what-do-i-do-when-a-question-cant-be-answered), right?

Comment: Maybe a bit. But it's not so much that it can't be answered as it's not an allowed question.

Comment: @Nathaniel I was just kidding.

Comment: @Locutus - prefer comments for jokes.

Comment: @Gnoupi its a joke comment.. you got the best of both worlds whoo hoo..

Answer (score 0):

> But in the last few days I have seen
>   several "web" questions that didn't
>   get closed.

Taking this quote, and with the example question provided in the link, the question was closed within 3 hours. I'd say that's pretty fast. FWIW I haven't seen an "increase" in the number of web questions being posted - might be the fact that the "closed" word sticks out more might make you believe that there has been a spurt in Web related questions.

Comment: Maybe so. Also I'm thinking that some of the web question that have popped up could be older ones.